# oracle ora-01722 invalid number where clause in update statement. I want to log this error in error log table

Tags: oracle

`oracle ora-01722` invalid number where clause in update statement. 
I want to log this error in error log table. How can i log??
Below is my Update statement, here empid is number.

```
UPDATE SARVESH_TEST_ERR_TB
SET    empid = empid
WHERE  empid ='aaa'
LOG ERRORS INTO SARVESH_ERR_LOGS_TB ('Error while UPDATE') 
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot(errors wont be logged) use error logging clause of a DML statement to log errors raised in the `WHERE` clause of the DML statement. Basically, DML(your `update` statement for instance) that includes `where` clause consists of two parts, writing part and reading one - so `where` clause is the reading part(basically a select/cursor) and you can use error logging clause to only catch errors the writing part of a DML statement raises. To be able to catch that error and write it into an error logging table, you could use `after servererror` trigger, but you wont be able to suppress that error:

```
/* test table */
SQL> create table tb_erp(
  2    col number
  3  )
  4  /
Table created

/* simple error logging table */
SQL> create table error_logs(
  2    msg varchar2(123)
  3  )
  4  /
Table created

SQL> insert into tb_erp(col) values(1);
1 row inserted

SQL> commit;
Commit complete

SQL> create or replace trigger TR_CATCH_ERRORS
  2  after servererror on schema
  3  begin
  4    insert into error_logs(msg)
  5      values(ora_server_error_msg(1));
  6  end;
  7  /
Trigger created
```

Test case:

```
SQL> update tb_erp t 
        set t.col = 5 
      where t.col = 'aaa';

update tb_erp t set t.col = 5 where t.col = 'aaa'
ORA-01722: invalid number

/* view errors */
SQL> select * 
  2    from error_logs;

MSG
-------------------------------
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

---

**EDIT #1**

> But i have to log the error message, error value('aaa'), created date/
>   error date ,whether it is insert/update statement Result set will be
>   Ora-01722:invalidnumber 'aaa' 23-oct-2013 'exception on insert/update'
>   . Is there any option like this

For this particular error you wont be able to extract the actual value(`'aaa'`), but what you can do, is to log an entire DML statement that causes an error:

`When` clause of the trigger allows you to list errors you what that trigger to fire for, otherwise it will fire for any error being raised.

```
SQL> alter table error_logs add ( text     varchar2(4000)
  2                             , timestmp timestamp )
  3  ;
Table altered


create or replace trigger TR_CATCH_ERRORS
after servererror on schema
--when ( ora_server_error(1) in ('1722') )
declare
  l_sql_txt_list ora_name_list_t;
  l_elements     binary_integer;
  l_sql_txt      varchar2(4000);

begin
  /* if statement triggering an error is long
    it'll be broken into several pieces and
    in order to get a complete statamet we have to assemble 
    those pieces */
  l_elements := ora_sql_txt(l_sql_txt_list);

  for i in 1..l_elements
  loop
    l_sql_txt := l_sql_txt || l_sql_txt_list(i);
  end loop;
  insert into error_logs(msg, text, timestmp)
    values( ora_server_error_msg(1)
           , l_sql_txt
           , systimestamp );
end;
```

Test case:

```
SQL> update tb_erp t set t.col = 5 where t.col = 'aaa';
update tb_erp t set t.col = 5 where t.col = 'aaa'
ORA-01722: invalid number

/* view errors */

SQL> select * from error_logs;

 MSG                        TEXT                     TIMESTMP
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ORA-01722: invalid number  update tb_erp t     23-OCT-13 11.04.57.535000 AM
                               set t.col = 5 
                             where t.col = 'aaa'
```

Comment: Thats fine..here in error_logs table your displaying only error message. But i have to log the error message, error value('aaa'), created date/ error date ,whether it is insert/update statement              Result set will be                                                                Ora-01722:invalidnumber   'aaa'  23-oct-2013   'exception on insert/update' . Is there any option like this.

Comment: @SarveshV Answer has been updated. For `insert` statements you can use error logging clause, but it will require you to maintain two separate error logging tables. Of course you can catch a log error raise by an `insert` statement using system event trigger but it has been mentioned they wont be suppressed.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas.. It is working fine Everything is logging in error table now. But i have a problem i will have list of Update satements suppose iam having 50 update statements and execption occured at 20th statement. Now what is happening is as per your suggestion it is logging the 20th statement but remaining 49 were not executing. I have to execute all statements wchich are not having any errors. What I mean is it has to exceute upto 19 statements successfully and at 20th one it will log into log table after that statements from 21 should start executing. Is there any chance for this??

Comment: Its ok Nicholas. It is working fine in SQL Plus editor. thank you.. i'm facing problem with toad. Any ways thank you for your support.

Comment: I got one more scenario.. My update statement is like:               UPDATE SARVESH_TEST_ERR2_TB
SET    empname = 109'
WHERE  empid =101;                                                       In this statement there is an ' after 109 it is throwing ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated error but it is not logging in error log table. can't we log those errors??

Comment: @SarveshV Those are compile-time errors, not run-time errors, so no, you wont be able to catch that error. On the other hand, you will be able to do that(catch run-time error that corresponds to that compile-time error) if you use dynamic(native dynamic SQL execute immediate for instance) to execute that update statement, but will such an approach suitable for you... Moreover, it's very strange that you are, having a column of number datatype, using quoted number literals in the update statement.

Comment: Nicholas, it do not suits for me. Why becoz i have to execute thousands of statements at a time and need to capture the queries what are failed to execute (error/compile/syntax/spellmistake..) wat ever the reason be to fail i want to store that one.I will get 1000's of queries through file and i can't edit all the thousands of queries with execute immediate manually. So this is my requirement, is there any solution for this??